# How do I use list comprehension to perform a mathematical operation on a matrix in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I must create a function, that takes a matrix as an argument and uses list comprehension to divide each element of the list by 2 if it is an even number.
So if the argument passed to the function was m = [[5, 4], [2, 3], [6, 7]]
The function would return the matrix m2 = [[5, 2], [1, 3], [3, 7]]

I have tried the following:

```
m = [[5, 4], [2, 3], [6, 7]]
result = [num / 2 for num in m if num % 2 == 0]
print (result)
```

But I receive this error:

```
line 2, in <listcomp>
    result = [num / 2 for num in m if num % 2 == 0]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: You have to try to create it with yourself , will help you if you get  problems

Comment: @JamesJameson please post the *full error message including the stack trace* in the question itself, don't post it in the comments

Comment: `[[e/2 if e%2==0 else e for e in sl] for sl in m]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you look for:

```
def divide_evens_elems_list(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst[i])):
            if lst[i][j]%2==0:
                lst[i][j]//=2

    return lst

m = [[5, 4], [2, 3], [6, 7]]
print(divide_evens_elems_list(m))
```

Comment: This doesn't use a list comprehension. Although, a list comprehension isn't really necessary. But more importantly, this modifies the argument in-place, which is generally an anti-pattern (sometimes you might want to for space efficiency sake, but usually it is bad and can lead to subtle bugs)

Comment: This is mono operation function , it's not necessary to keep the original list .

Comment: what? It *does* keep the original list. The **problem** is that it mutates the list that is passed in as an argument, which is typically considered bad.